# How to delete data from database with conditions?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on messaging android app ,all data is saved in sqlite database. There are 3 activities ,but message of that three activities saves in one table my_chat. Now I want to delete data of particular project chat & module.

Example- I want to delete data of first project where type is first_module but last inserted data in table is type third_module.

Here is my query

```
"DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND module_text ='" + module_type + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat order by id desc limit 2)"
```

First time it works perfectly but when we add data of any other module then this query do not delete last two message of particular module.

Comment: You should use the WHERE clause inside the inner SELECT query so that module_text ='" + module_type + "'

Comment: I am already using limit 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WHERE clause inside the inner SELECT.

```
"DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND module_text ='" + module_type + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat WHERE module_text ='" + module_type + "' order by id desc limit 2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `order by id desc limit 2`

```
DELETE FROM my_chat WHERE project_id ='" + project_id + "' AND module_text ='" + module_type + "' AND id in (select id from my_chat order)
```